# PowerShell Copy-Item PathTooLongException

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script where I need to copy to a folder recursively, replacing all the files in it:

```
Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination -Recurse -Force -Verbose
```

Since some of the files in the destination folder have a path that exceeds 260 chars I am getting a PathTooLongException.

I have read about these possible solutions:

1. Use robocopy

   - I rather use pure PowerShell
2. Enable long paths in registry & group policy

   - requires the user to have to restart his console and I also prefer not changing the user's registry.
3. Use a `\\?\` prefix for the paths

As I said, I rather not use the first two, the third solution (`\\?\`) should be fine for me, but the files are not actually being copied.

When it executes it completes immediately and no output from the command is generated. As a result, the files in the destination are not replaced with the files from the source.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are these UNC paths (`\\server,share`) or local paths (`X:\`) ?

Comment: All paths are local paths.

Comment: **use robocopy** - it's _robust_. it's WELL tested. it's FREAKING FAST. [*grin*] it's the correct tool for the job. posh/not-posh is not the idea to look at - the correct idea is "right tool or not". robocopy works really, really well from inside a posh script. [*grin*]

Answer (score 4):

The `\\?\` prefix makes use of the unicode version of Windows API, this needs to use the `LiteralPath` param instead of `Path`:

```
Copy-Item -LiteralPath '\\?\C:\folder\subfolder' -Destination 'D:\folder'
```

---

The syntax for UNC path `\\server\share\folder` is slightly different `\\?\UNC\server\share\folder`

(Not specifically relevant to you, but for future reference if anyone stumbles across this answer)

Comment: Copy-Item : Illegal characters in path.
At D:\Code\TestCopy.ps1:144 char:5
+     Copy-Item -LiteralPath $source -Destination $destination -Recurse -Fo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand